# Artifactory Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Tags: maven, artifactory

I've installed the Artifactory-oss helm chart on a Kubernetes cluster.
I set up an ingress to point to the `artifactory-oss-artifactory-nginx` pod that has been generated by the Helm chart.

This is the description of the ingress:

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    field.cattle.io/creatorId: user-tlw59
    field.cattle.io/ingressState: '{"YXJ0aWZhY3Rvcnktb3Nz":"artifactory-oss:artifactory-oss","YXJ0aWZhY3RvcnkvYXJ0aWZhY3Rvcnktb3NzL2FydGlmYWN0b3J5LmFkaWJveC5iZS8vODA=":"deployment:artifactory-oss:artifactory-oss-artifactory-nginx"}'
    field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints: '[{"addresses":["<ip node 1>","<ip node 2>","<ip node 3>","<ip node 4>"],"port":443,"protocol":"HTTPS","serviceName":"artifactory-oss:ingress-45026c7764095d3b3dfc9d407edfe632","ingressName":"artifactory-oss:artifactory","hostname":"artifactory.mydomain.com","allNodes":false}]'
  creationTimestamp: "2020-01-10T14:02:53Z"
  generation: 4
  labels:
    cattle.io/creator: norman
  name: artifactory
  namespace: artifactory-oss
  resourceVersion: "17198082"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/artifactory-oss/ingresses/artifactory
  uid: 7ad9ce13-a1fe-46f4-bb4a-6aaa1e2aa902
spec:
  rules:
  - host: artifactory.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: ingress-45026c7764095d3b3dfc9d407edfe632
          servicePort: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - artifactory.mydomain.com
    secretName: artifactory-oss
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: <ip node 1>
    - ip: <ip node 2>
    - ip: <ip node 3>
    - ip: <ip node 4>
```

I went into my Artifactory Repository Browser and set up "libs-release-local" and "libs-snapshot-local" and copying the xml into my `pom.xml`.

```
<distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>artifactory-oss-artifactory-0-releases</name>
            <url>https://artifactory.mydomain.be:80/artifactory/libs-release-local</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>artifactory-oss-artifactory-0-snapshots</name>
            <url>https://artifactory.mydomain.be:80/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

And finally I run

```
mvn deploy
```

Which gives me the following error:

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project mylibrary: Failed to retrieve remote metadata com.mydomain:mylibrary:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata com.mydomain:mylibrary:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to snapshots (https://artifactory.mydomain.com:80/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local): Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Also, I do not have any `.m2/settings.xml`, do I need one ? If yes what should I add to it ?

Any idea on what is wrong here ?

**EDIT**

1. I remove the `:80` from the URL. This has solved the original issue.
2. I've copied the settings.xml into `.m2/settings.xml` from the artifactory `Set me up` but I'm now stuck with a

   > Not authorized

Thanks.

Comment: Just taking a guess here, but did you try setting the port to 443?
This error is usually related to wrong connection to http/https servers

Comment: changing to https://artifactory.mydomain.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local) (removing port) changes the error message to `unable to find valid certification path to requested target`. At least it seems to have fixed the original issue, thank you.

Comment: If I go to  artifactory.mydomain.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local on a browser it display an empty list but seems to be working on browser

Comment: See if this can help:
https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-resolve-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-error/

Comment: Thanks. I'm now a step forward. The error is now "Not authorized". I've created another SO issue because this is not related to this issue title: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59718080/artifactory-mvn-deploy-not-auhorized