# Artifactory mvn deploy not auhorized

Tags: maven, artifactory

I have installed artifactory-oss on a kubernetes cluster but I can't manage to deploy on it using maven.

When I run `mvn deploy` I have this error

```
.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to snapshots (https://artifactory.adibox.be/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local): Not authorized -> [Help 1]
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>be.adibox</groupId>
    <artifactId>adiboxorm</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>annotations</module>
    </modules>

    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>artifactory-oss-artifactory-0-snapshots</name>
            <url>https://artifactory.adibox.be/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

And here is my settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <username>${security.getCurrentUsername()}</username>
      <password>${security.getEscapedEncryptedPassword()!"<myencryptedpassword>"}</password>
      <id>central</id>
    </server>
    <server>
      <username>${security.getCurrentUsername()}</username>
      <password>${security.getEscapedEncryptedPassword()!"<myencryptedpassword>"}</password>
      <id>snapshots</id>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <name>libs-snapshot</name>
      <url>https://artifactory.adibox.be/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
      <id>libs-snapshot</id>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <url>https://artifactory.adibox.be/artifactory/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>libs-snapshot</name>
          <url>https://artifactory.adibox.be/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <url>https://artifactory.adibox.be/artifactory/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>libs-snapshot</name>
          <url>https://artifactory.adibox.be/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>artifactory</id>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>

</settings>
```

At first the URL generated by artifactory was `https://artifactory.adibox.be:80/artifactory/libs-snapshot` but I was getting an SSL error. I removed the `:80` and I result in the error specified above.

Any idea what could be wrong ?
Is it because Artifactory is deployed on a Kubernetes cluster ?

I'm able to see the list of artifacts in the browser by going to 
https://artifactory.adibox.be/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local and entering my credentials.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to put the username/pwd in clear in settingx.xml just to make sure your account works

Comment: Yes I tried with them in clear text with every combinations of username, email, clear password, encrypted password. I just didn't try "escaped password" because I'm not sure what the `getEscapedEncryptedPassword` is actually doing.

Comment: I guess it means you can connect, right? Maybe you need to look at the permissions: your account must be authorised to deploy a new artifact (sort of write or deploy privilege)

Comment: "I guess it means you can connect, right?". I would say no. Maybe I didn't explained it correctly but if I set clear username and password I got the exact same error "Not Authorized". Plus, the user I try to connect with is marked as "admin".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar error with Nexus deployed on gcp.

Comparing my settings with your settings, I think you need the mirror id. In my case : **nexus-releases**

As you can see in my attached settings, `<server>` defines an user/password with an id       `<id>nexus-releases</id>`.

Then in mirror section, its has and id with the same value of server id: **nexus-releases**

```
<settings>
  <pluginGroups></pluginGroups>
  <proxies></proxies>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>nexus-releases</id>
      <username>jane</username>
      <password>doe</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>nexus-releases</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <name>central</name>
      <url>https://mynexus.com/repository/maven-public/</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles></profiles>
</settings>
```

Finally at deploy, this id **nexus-releases** is required too:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgeneratePom=false -DrepositoryId=nexus-releases -Durl=https://mynexus.com/repository/maven-releases/ -DpomFile=pom.xml -Dfile=myjar-1.0.0.jar
```

---

Anyway if error continues, I advice you the steps to reproduce your issue. If you cannot reproduce the issue, you can not find a solution.

- Try with localhost artifactory. Could be an error in kuberentes, gcp , aws , etc
- Use an empty m2 repo and ensure that your seetinng.xml is used. You could that append this sentences to your mvn deploy command :

```
    -s /tmp/my_settings.xml -Dmaven.repo.local=/tmp/m2
```

- Try to use linux instead windows.

Comment: "ensure that your seetinng.xml is used". That was the trick. I was using an obscure global settings.xml somewhere. Thanks for the tips.